# zsh multiline prompt moves along with the input, and disappears after running command

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, kde-plasma

Here are some of the images of my zsh terminal.

[image: The Prompt does not appear in the executed commands, while pressing enter, the prompt moves to the new line]

[image: The command disappears while typing the password]

[image: And this is how it behaves while typing the command "echo " with multiline]

I use I use kubuntu latest version, ( if it matters ).

The terminal behaves differently for commands like echo '
hello
world
good'

The prompt disappears while typing passwords.
The prompt moves along the new line it does not remain...

Following image is how I want it to be. The prompt should remain even after running the command.

[image: This is how it should be]

Comment: Here is my .p10k.zsh file:
https://pastebin.com/04LcEv55

Comment: Your normal prompt is in `PS1`. You are seeing your secondary prompt, specified by `PS2`, following `echo '`.

Comment: The password prompt comes from `sudo` itself; it has nothing to do with your shell.

Comment: @chepner what about the first picture...?

Comment: What about? There's probably something in your prompt that suppresses the directory if you are in your home directory. This question isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow, as it is not about programming. Try unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.